# Mongodb aggregate collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm learning aggregate in mongodb. I'm working with the collection:

```
                    {
                            "body" : ""
     ,
                    "email" : "oJJFLCfA@qqlBNdpY.com",
                    "author" : "Linnie Weigel"
            },
            {
                    "body" : ""
     ,
                    "email" : "ptHfegMX@WgxhlEeV.com",
                    "author" : "Dinah Sauve"
            },
            {
                    "body" : ""
    ,
                    "email" : "kfPmikkG@SBxfJifD.com",
                    "author" : "Zachary Langlais"
            }
            {
                    "body" : ""
     ,
                    "email" : "gqEMQEYg@iiBqZCez.com",
                    "author" : "Jesusa Rickenbacker"
            }
    ]
```

I try to obtain the number of body of each author. But when I execute  the command sum of aggregate mongodb, the result is 1(because the structure has only one element) . How can I do this operation?. I tried with $addToSet. But I don't know how to obtain each element of collection and to do the operation.

Comment: Could you please include the code you used? Also is this from your mongodb university assignment?

Comment: You say "execute the command sum" - there is no such command.  Are you talking about $group stage where you can use $sum operator to get your answer (as long as you're grouping on the right field).

Comment: My code is var group = {$group:{_id:"$author",total:{$addToSet:"$comments.author"}}}:

Comment: var group1 = {$group:{id:"$total",count:{$sum:1}}};db.posts.aggregate([group,group1})

Comment: The result is the names of authors and count 1. This is wrong. I want to find the author and the number of bodies. How can I obtain and array with all authors and after to do a count of bodies

Comment: I obtain a field count at end of list of authors.This field has the value of 1

Answer (score 3):

In order to count the comments by each author you want to [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) by that author and [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the occurrences. Basically just a "$sum: 1" operation. But it seems like you have "comments" as an array here based on your own comments and the closing bracket on your partial data listing. For that you need to process with [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$unwind": "$comments" },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$comments.author",
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }}
])
```

That will obtain the total of all author comments by author for the entire collection. If you were just after getting the total comments by author per document ( or what looks like a blog post model ) then you use the document `_id` as part of the group statement:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$unwind": "$comments" },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": {
           "_id": "$_id"
           "author": "$comments.author"
       },
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }}
])
```

And if you then want the summary of author counts per document with just a single document returned with all the authors in an array, then use [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) from here, with another [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$unwind": "$comments" },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": {
           "_id": "$_id"
           "author": "$comments.author"
       },
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }},
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id._id",
       "comments": {
           "$addToSet": {
               "author": "$_id.author",
               "count": "$count"
           }
       }
   }}
])
```

But really, the author values are already unique and "sets" are not ordered in any way, so you might change this using [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) after first introducing a [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to have the list ordered by the number of comments made:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
   { "$unwind": "$comments" },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": {
           "_id": "$_id"
           "author": "$comments.author"
       },
       "count": { "$sum": 1 }
   }},
   { "$sort": { "_id._id": 1, "count": -1 } },
   { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id._id",
       "comments": {
           "$push": {
               "author": "$_id.author",
               "count": "$count"
           }
       }
   }}
])
```